# Convert RGB colors to DMC floss colors

Tags: r, excel, rgb

I'm trying to find an automated way to calculate what [DMC color](https://www.dmc.com/us/six-strand-embroidery-floss-489-colors-available-9003292.html#null) is closest to a given RGB. I found this site:

http://www.damaniel.info/dmc/dmctorgb.html

And that does what I want. However, I have to type each RGB is separately and I have a lot of them.

I'd like to use formulas to automate the calculate. Preferably in Excel or in R. I haven't had luck with Selenium (and don't have much spare time right now to get up to speed), so that might not be the best option for doing automated form filling with the above site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DMC R package (<sup>1</sup>) will help with that. It looks like it only supports hexadecimal codes, but you can convert RGB colors using the `rgb` function from the `grDevices` package (Use `maxColorValue = 255` if you are using `RGB` versus `rgb`).

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("sharlagelfand/dmc")
library(dmc)


# convert rbg to hex
# second green color from ColorBrewer.org
# (3-class BuGn second color)
color <- grDevices::rgb(red = 153, green = 216, blue = 201, maxColorValue = 255)

# find dmc - return a few more results
color_dmc <- dmc(color, n = 3)
color_dmc
```

If you have a few colors, you can wrap this in a loop or apply function and write the dmc values to a master object by extracting the elements you need (i.e., `color_dmc$hex`, `color_dmc$name`, etc.)

<sup>1</sup> https://github.com/sharlagelfand/dmc

Comment: Great suggestion, just don't forget to change the `method` argument to `"cie2000"` or one of the others.  `euclidean` is a terrible choice for a default.

Comment: Thanks so much! I applied this with dplyr to a whole data frame using the mutate function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of RGB values corresponding to DMC floss colors here: http://my.crazyartzone.com/dmc.asp .  There's also a list built in to the source code for the web page you found (and it's different).   You can see that list at this URL:  http://www.damaniel.info/dmc/dmctorgb.js .

Why are they different?  There are different standards for RGB.  The most common one is now called sRGB (for "Standard RGB").  They might be using different standards.  Or maybe they are getting their colors from different sources. They are approximate, anyway:  floss varies in color.  So just pick one.

Then what you would need to do is to take your RGB value and find the nearest value in one of those lists.

This isn't trivial, because defining "nearest" is hard.  What that web page appears to do is to use Euclidean distance in RGB space, but that space is far from perceptually uniform.  So it's probably best to convert both your input RGB color and the table of floss colors to some other representation where equal distances are perceptually equal.  I think the LAB space (see `?colorspace::LAB`) is probably a good choice for that, but I don't know if it's best.  Read http://colorspace.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/color_spaces.html if you want to dig into the details.

So here's what you need to do:

1. Load a version of one of those tables into a dataframe.
2. Convert all the RGB values there into LAB values, and add those to the dataframe.
3. Write a function to convert your input RGB value to LAB.
4. Find the nearest LAB entry in the dataframe to the LAB value you want, and output the corresponding floss number.

EDITED TO ADD:  While I was writing that, @dcruvolo pointed out the nice `dmc` package.  So use that!  (Maybe you want to change how it does distance; you really don't want the default Euclidean distance in RGB space.)